# Qt Creator C++: Storing lineEdit inputs in array

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

This might come off as a very stupid question, but I have to write a very simple program, consisting of a line edit and push button. 
This program has to be able to take inputs(numbers) from the user in the line edit area and every time the push button is pressed, store the number values within an array of size 10.

I have some experience with C++ but am just generally very confused with the GUI aspects of Qt. The GUI stuff is just way over my head so I apologize again if this is trivial! But if anyone could help me figure out how to do this you would be the coolest.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Designer of Qt Creator, or doing the GUI in C++?

Comment: Also note, Qt Creator is just an IDE. There's no such thing as "Qt Creator C++" (it could mean writing QtC plugins with C++ I suppose, but clearly you are not doing that).

Answer (score 0):

Put lineEdit and button on form in Qt Designer or create it by yourself:

Create slot in header:

```
private slots:
void mySlot();

//do connection in dialog's constructor


    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(mySlot()));

//Write slot

void Dialog::mySlot()
{
QString str = ui->lineEdit->text()
//now str contains all your text you can put it in different arrays.
}
```

`text()` return QString, but if you sure that it is double, then call toDouble() method

```
QString str = ui->lineEdit->text().replace(",",".")
double var = str.toDouble();
```

Moreover you can set `QDoubleValidator` to `lineEdit` and user can input only double in this lineEdit. Search in web what validator is and use `setValidator()` method to set it to lineEdit.

Comment: thanks that looks great except it says that i can't take numbers this way, the inputs are meant to be doubles, is there another function i can use rather than the text() one for number values? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Things need to do

1. set a button and a lineedit either in ui or in constructor of mywindows.
2. set validator for int.
3. declare a slot for button, to pass the int in lineEdit to your data structure.
4. fixed array is not enough to store all the user input, you need to think about whether you need is a list, a dynamic array, a fixed array of stack or queue.

---

### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QList>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

private slots:
  void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  QList<int> m_list;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

### mainwindows.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0, 9999, this));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  m_list.append(ui->lineEdit->displayText().toInt());
  qDebug() << m_list;
}
```